# Bathymetry of Quarry Lake in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've been asked to do a project that maps the bathymetry of a quarry lake. It seems like I've seen a feature in QGIS that would help with this if I took a bunch of depth points in the lake. Any thoughts on where to find this? And how to do it?

And there's not a chance this data could already exist somewhere from remote sensing, soil surveys, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is almost global bathymetry coverage, but I doubt it is precise enough for your quarry. Check this similar question for both the source and a pointer to GRASS (which can be used from QGIS) and a conversion option: [How to use SRTM30 Plus data with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23583/7913)

If you measure enough points, you could create contours normally. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19/55-how-to-generate-contours-using-point-data-in-quantum-gis-qgis.html).